# How to implement background process

Tags: c#, wcf

How to run a background process in C# ? 
My requirement is to trigger a process from application which will run more than 30 mins . I have to show the updated status of process on screen every now and then. Could anyone suggest me a option in implementing this ?
I have used WCF service in app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My options are:

1. Use a backgroundworker process and perform the long running operation, mean while use a loading image to display work is in progress. Since you are using wcf service to get response back, it is difficult to show actual work progress.

2. Use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and delegate the long running process to threadpool threads. Then using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [One-Way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx) calls and Callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

If the long process is performed in the wcf service then run it using a background worker thread. Implement the notify progress and update a special table on a database (if there is one available). Create another method of the wcf service that checks and returns the state of the process (by reading the table) and call it from the app.

Edit:

Read about how to use [Background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Use it in you service to run the heavy work. When you run the backround thread the service should return a response. Then update in the table that you can log the status of the work that the thread is on.
Implement a [timer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer) on your application and call back on the service to read the status of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comments. I am new to this Threading conecept and service ..If possible could you please share code snippet about this ?

Comment: As suggested i can use a table to log the updates about running process. But i m not sure about calling threads and using asynchronous service calls